# CSS overflow issue in Firefox

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-float

I have a table coded as follows;

```
<table id="c_month_tbl" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="weekend_days">
<div class="block_out">
<div class="blockout_text">Some content ...Some content ...Some content ...Some content ...Some content ...</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS is as follows;

```
    td.weekend_days .blockout_text {
        margin-top: 14px;
    }
    .blockout_text {
        margin-top: 25px;
        padding: 3px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #c_month_tbl{
        clear: both;
        width: 678px;
    }
    .block_out {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Now the layout appears fine if the content inside the td is less...But if there is more content, IE kind of expands the cell width/height and displays the content fine.

But in Firefox, the width/height for the content div remains fixed and does not expand as per the content, which makes the layout appear a bit broken..

I tried changing the overflow property for the containing td/div element , but it is not working fine in Firefox.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: What firefox version do you use? in 6.0.2 seems all works like in other browsers http://jsfiddle.net/MeL2F/

Comment: I am using Firefox 4.0.1

Comment: @testndtv: have you found a solution for that?

Comment: What happens when you remove "height:50px;" in the css of the block_out div. I think that IE ignores the rule.

Comment: I hope your not using the table for layout purposes. Tables should be used for displaying tabular data in an orderly form.

Comment: If you have a solution, can you please post it and close this item? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class `.blockout`, or remove the height restriction on it. If you want it to be *at least* 50px tall, use `min-height` instead.